# Angular 2 : Aot not generating app folder

Tags: angular, angular2-aot

I have implemented aot in my Angular 2 project, resolved all errors an finally my

```
"node_modules/.bin/ngc" -p tsconfig-aot.json
```

run successfully but I see only node_modules folder in aot folder and no app folder in it. So where can I get **AppModuleNgFactory**  to bootstrap it?

Answer (score 1):

Downgrading `typescript` to `2.0.2` solved the problem for me. (Depending on your angular version)

**package.json**:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "2.0.2" <-- make it like this
```

Remove your `typescript` module inside **node_modules** folder and run an `npm install` again.

Similar problems: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10792

Comment: I agree. It also helped me in similar cituation. +1